# Use selected value from DropDownList in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a dropdown list of "TIPS" and depending on the one you select I multiply the total by the tip percentage to find the entire total.

I currently have

```
<select name="DropDownList1">
    <option value="0">None</option>
    <option value="10">10%</option>
    <option value="12">12%</option>
    <option value="15">15%</option>
    <option value="18">18%</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="22">22%</option>
    <option value="25">25%</option>
</select>
```

I pretty much need to somehow tell which one was selected and using that I make my tip and new total. Any help on how to do that? MVC 5 - C#

Comment: Your `<select>` tag does not have a `name` attribute so it's value won't post back to your controller. Create a view model with a property (say int Tip { get; set; } and a `SelectList` for the options and use the strongly typed `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Tip, Model.TipList)` to property generate your html.

Comment: But it only submits it when there is a "Submit" button, I want it to automatically generate that total.

Comment: Based on the edit there is now a `name` attribute so it will now post back. In the controller, just use its value as a multiplier to apply to the other property (or do you want to do this on the client side as well?). You have not even shown the other property so impossible to give you an answer

Comment: And what do you mean _"only submits it when there is a "Submit" button"_? What is the point of a form if you can't submit it

Comment: Sorry i thought I explained it in my post. I pretty much want it so that someone has an option to choose the % of tip they want. Once that is done, I need to somehow be able to know which value was selected and use that value.

Comment: As I noted, you now post back a name/pair value which is `DropDownList1: theValueOfTheSelectedOption` so you do know what the selected value is.

Comment: It needs to do it automatically without there being a "Submit"

Comment: If you want to get the selected value when a new value is selected, just add a onchange event to your select (onchange = "$(this).parents('form').submit();" ) and get the value of your dropdown in the controller.

Comment: Do what automatically? Are you wanting to update some element the current page? (if so you need javascript/jquery). Show you view and indicate which element(s) you want to update. How on earth do you expect anyone to guess what your trying to do.